# Django: Give date field default value of one month from today

Tags: django, django-models, datefield

In Django, you can have a date field and set the default value to today.

```
start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
```

How do you set the default date to 1 month from today?

Comment: Is it impossible to do it manually? 
start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now.replace(month=timezone.now.month-1)), or something like this?

Comment: @Snipper03 That won't work because `timezone.now` is not a datetime value but a callable, i.e. a reference to a function.

Comment: Yes right, it's function in django.utils. Then how about launch a function that getting date of a month ago,  as a method of model? like get_date_one_month_ago, and  call it in the definition area of model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any callable as a default value, so that should work:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def one_month_from_today():
    return timezone.now() + timedelta(days=30)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    start_date = models.DateField(default=one_month_from_today, blank=True, null=True)
```

Note that I used `days=30` as `timedelta` can't add a *month* to a date value. If you think of it, "one month from today" is a pretty open statement (how do you want it to behave when today is January 31, for example?).

Comment: an exact month isn't necessary, 30 days will suffice. If you realyl wanted to do a month then you could get the current month and year and add number of days in that month to it. Thanks, this works for me!